# Poor performance when holding down accelerator key for Undo

Tags: java, performance, swing, hotkeys, accelerator

I have bound a menu item to invoke the undo method of an undomanager on a jtextpane, and assigned an "accelerator" key combination to that undo invoke of the standard Ctrl-Z. The undo behaves just as I would like it to, unless I **hold down** Ctrl-Z. When I do that, the undo's are performed at an unpredictable cadence, often freezing for 5 seconds, then doing a batch of undos all at once. I do not know why this is happening, becuase if I rapidly press Ctrl-Z there seems to be no limit to how fast it will go, implying there is no intrinsic performance issue with the undo method.

Comment: Do any other accelerator keys do this? "Paste", for example?

Comment: Paste does not have this issue, but I am using the built-in hotkey for pasting, which I think is defined in the JTextComponent sub-class.

Comment: Is it possible to get some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're mistaking the key repeat delay for the "freezing"?